# Laravel Broadcasting: Private Channel Authentication Issue with Nwidart Module

Tags: laravel, laravel-echo, broadcasting, laravel-broadcast

I'm encountering a 403 error when attempting to authenticate private channels in Laravel Broadcasting with the Nwidart module. Specifically, the error occurs at the route http://127.0.0.1:8080/broadcasting/auth, as shown in the browser console.

This issue seems specific to Nwidart, as it works seamlessly when not using the module. When logged in to the advertiser module (where only the advertiser module is authenticated), the broadcasting system can't locate any authenticated user to use for the private channel.

My Tries:
I've defined a custom event (CredentialView) in the Modules\Advertiser\Events namespace, along with a corresponding private channel in the routes/channels.php file. Additionally, I've ensured that the necessary broadcasting configurations are uncommented in the config/app.php file.

```
// CredentialView event class
class CredentialView implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $credential;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($credential)
    {
        $this->credential = $credential;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should be broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('credential-view.' . $this->credential->advertiser_id);
    }
}
```

```
// Channel route
Broadcast::channel('credential-view.{advertiserId}', function ($user, Advertiser $advertiser) {
    return true; // Temporary implementation for testing
});
```

```
// Route to fire the event
Route::get('/event', function () {
    // Code to retrieve and fire the CredentialView event...
});
```

**Configurations:**
Here's a snippet of my config/auth.php setup:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'admin',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'advertiser' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'advertisers',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'advertisers' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => Modules\Advertiser\Entities\Advertiser::class,
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that each reset token will be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

**Question:**
What could be causing the 403 error when trying to authenticate private channels in Laravel Broadcasting with the Nwidart module, and how can I resolve it?
My laravel version: 9.2. nwidart module version: 9.0